# Is it possible to use several glossaries for requests in GCP translate advanced v3?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I'm working on a feature allowing users to select "General glossaries" (like automotive, finance) in addition of their personal glossary for requests.

After checking the documentation, it seems only possible to provide 1 glossary for a request, but I would like to know if someone already found a solution to make requests with several glossaries.

From the Google Cloud Documentation on [translating text with a glossary (nodejs)](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/glossary#translate_v3_translate_text_with_glossary-nodejs):

[image: Code snippet from google doc]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, we are merging the glossaries words list on the back-end side before uploading the glossary, so each user can have its own configuration.

Hope it helps someone as it seems not possible to give an array of glossaries per request.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I made a few edits to improve formatting. It will enrich your answer if you provide some code, like the one that you use to merge the glossaries.